# Is it valid (in theory and practice)to pass numerical token to BERT directly?

Tags: deep-learning, bert-language-model

I'm wondering if I have text for example ...

```
from transformers import BertModel
bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

from transformers import BertTokenizerFast
tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', do_lower_case=True)

text = "In 2020, I was 16 years old"
sent_id = tokenizer.encode(text, 
                           # add [CLS] and [SEP] tokens
                           add_special_tokens=True,
                           # specify maximum length for the sequences                                  
                           max_length = 10,
                           truncation = True,
                           # add pad tokens to the right side of the sequence
                           pad_to_max_length='right')                       
# print integer sequence
print("Integer Sequence: {}".format(sent_id))
# convert integers back to text
print("Tokenized Text:",tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(sent_id))
```

I got the following results.

```
Integer Sequence: [101, 1999, 12609, 1010, 1045, 2001, 2385, 2086, 2214, 102]
Tokenized Text: ['[CLS]', 'in', '2020', ',', 'i', 'was', '16', 'years', 'old', '[SEP]']
```

Although there was no error, I'm not sure whether it is valid (by theory and practice) to pass numerical tokens (2020 and 16) directly to BERT.  Do we need to make some special token for them in order to make BERT know numeracy?